# Question on the bounds for finding Fourier coefficients

Tags: electromagnetism, conventions, fourier-transform, spherical-harmonics, special-functions

In Griffit's E&M, when solving Laplace's equation for the potential, he uses the "Fourier trick" on Legendre polynomials, where [image]

my question is, why are the bounds from -1 to 1?
because if $x = \cos(\theta)$ we get that $$\int_{0}^\pi {P_l(\cos(\theta))P_{l'}(\cos(\theta)) \sin(\theta)d\theta}$$

but ${0,\pi}$ is only half a period for $\cos(\theta)$ (full domain is $0,2\pi)$

so why do we only say that the functions are orthogonal for half the domain?

Comment: It's just the substitution you indicated, $x=\cos(\theta)$. There is no reason to expect "a full $2\pi$ period".

Comment: Sure, but  why are the bounds -1,1 in the first place?

Comment: Oh, sorry, in the first place. That's just the range for the orthogonality relation in the Legendre polynomials. I guess historically they could have been defined with a different dominion or even normalization, but that's just the conventional choice.

Comment: Is there a text that you can reference me to which motivates this domain, where the Legendre polynomials are orthogonal?

Comment: For information on Legendre-like polynomials with different orthogonalization domains, check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1924557/legendre-polynomial-on-interval-a-b-other-than-1-1) answer. I think the question of the rationalization behind the conventional choice may fit in the *math* or even the *history of science and math* stackexchange sites more than here.